# header location CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

2 Scenarios:

```
header("Location: login/$username");
```

gives me

```
http://localhost/login/login/mylogin
```

AND

```
header("Location: /$username");
```

gives me:

```
http://localhost/mylogin
```

Both are wrong. I want `http://localhost/login/mylogin`

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
redirect('login/'.$username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not manipulate headers this way in CI.

For a redirect use `redirect()`

and for headers use `$this->output->set_header()`

Answer (score 0):

`redirect(base_url("login/".$username));` will redirect as you request

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.base_url("login/".$username).'";</script>';
```